# "However" and "but" together

Tags: conjunctions

I saw a sentence on English Language and Usage SE that goes:

> This is probably borderline archaic or dialect-dependent, ***however***, ***but*** other terms are that as well: maid, maiden, lassie, colleen, etc. (From [Robusto's answer)](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/562650/387044)

This sentence sounds somewhat awkward to me. My understanding is that "however" and "but" are almost the same word ("however" being formal and "but" being informal), although I'm not very sure about the above construction. Do "however" and "but" have different meanings in the above sentence? In what situations can I use them like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't have different meanings, but they link different parts of the answer. The full answer is:

> If you can't use girl, you could try (definition of *lass*). This is probably borderline archaic or dialect-dependent, however, but other terms are that as well: maid, maiden, lassie, colleen, etc.

The *however* stands between the first sentence of the answer and the first part of the second sentence, the *but* stands between two parts of the second sentence. In other words:

- If you can't use *girl*, you could try *lass*
- **but** this is probably borderline archaic or dialect-dependent
- **but** other terms are that as well.

What can be a bit confusing is that when *however* is used to link two sentences instead of two clauses of the same sentence, it can be put either at the start or at the end of the second sentence:

> This is an archaic word. However, you could still use it.
>
> This is an archaic word. You could still use it, however.

And that's what happened here - the second sentence had its *however* moved to the end, and then had a *but-* clause further attached to it, resulting in this awkward combination of words.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks